# How to delete specific word from DeepDiff?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, diff, deep-diff

I need that code for compate of structure 2-yaml files, And I have some trouble with DeepDiff object.

File1:

```
app:
  mainkey:
    key1: 60
    key2: 5
  mainkey2:
    key1: 120
    key2: 5
  mainkey3:
    test: value
```

File2:

```
app:
  mainkey:
    key1: 120
    key2: 5
```

app:

```
import yaml
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

with open("file1.yaml", "r") as f1:
        f1 = f1.read()
        f1 = yaml.safe_load(f1)
with open("file2.yaml", "r") as f2:
        f2 = f2.read()
        f2 = yaml.safe_load(f2)

diffs = DeepDiff(f1, f2)
print(diffs['dictionary_item_removed'])
print(type(diffs['dictionary_item_removed']))
```

`$ python3 app.py`

Output:

```
[root['app']['mainkey2'], root['app']['mainkey3']]
<class 'deepdiff.model.PrettyOrderedSet'>
```

Expect:
`['app']['mainkey2'], ['app']['mainkey3']`

How to delete that .... `root` word from DeepDiff object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import yaml
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

with open("file1.yaml", "r") as f1:
        f1 = f1.read()
        f1 = yaml.safe_load(f1)
with open("file2.yaml", "r") as f2:
        f2 = f2.read()
        f2 = yaml.safe_load(f2)

diffs = DeepDiff(f1, f2)
print(str(diffs['dictionary_item_removed']).replace('root','')[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
['app']['mainkey3'], ['app']['mainkey2']
```

The result is a string. You can convert it into a list by using `.split(', ')`.